# How share a library on Android

Tags: android, project, shared-libraries

I want to build a java library with some useful things I done to Android. Just like my other project: https://github.com/MarkyVasconcelos/Towel

My question is, what is the best way to share a library on Android?

Source codes from a entirely Android project(res, src, Manifest, etc..)?
Only source codes(.java)?
A generated jar with the 'src' folder?

Thanks.

Comment: jar is not an option if you need to provide resources with your components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although never done myself I think you have to provide an [Android Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject) if your library contains android specific content.

Answer (score 2):

I'd distribute an Android library project. I have [several](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge) [such](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) [projects](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-sacklist) in my various GitHub repositories -- those links are just three of 'em.